# how to center image when browser resizes and make responsive inside figure tag

Tags: html, css

I have a figure tag, I want to make it responsive, and I want to center the  the figure tag when the browser resizes, i have the next code snippet that describes my code, please give me a little help here. thanks

```css
.mover2{
 position:relative;
 left:-33%;
 top:-8%;
 width: 100%;
 height: 77%;
 display: block;
}

.arreglo2{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display:block;
}

#mas2{
 background: rgba(43,86,162,1.00);
 
}

figcaption.efectoimg2 p{
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Arial;
 color:rgba(253,253,253,1.00);
 font-weight: bold;
 position:relative;
 bottom: 15px;
 font-size:100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/imagehover.css/1.0/css/imagehover.min.css">


 <figure class="imghvr-push-up mover2">
   <img class="arreglo2" src="https://i.imgur.com/D4fiyHr.png">
   <figcaption class="efectoimg2" id="mas2">
     <p>Atención Al Usuario</p>
     </figcaption>
 </figure>
```

Comment: its possibly to center the figure tag with the image when the browser resizes?

Comment: please any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve what you asked for, you need to use media queries. You can learn more about them [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/)

You have to add this to your code, which will change the style of the `<figure>` when you view it on a different screen size

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1100px){ /* You can choose whichever width you want */
  .mover2{
    margin:auto;
    left:inherit;
    top:inherit;
    float:none;
  }
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/30ptcjyx/